# Fatal error: Call to undefined function UNIX_TIMESTAMP() in /

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am trying to change my database from MySQL to PDO. It is difficult and have to solve a lot of errors.

I don't know how to solve this error.

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function UNIX_TIMESTAMP() in /... on line 63.

This is the part with the error

```
function create_album($album_name, $album_description) {
    global $database;
    $database->query("INSERT INTO albums(album_id, id, timestamp, name, description)
        VALUES (':album_id', '".$_SESSION['id']."', 
        UNIX_TIMESTAMP(), ':album_name', ':album_description')", array('$_SESSION[id]' => ':session_id',
        ':timestamp' => UNIX_TIMESTAMP(), ':album_name' => $album_name, ':album_description' => $album_description));//this is line 63 

    mkdir('uploads/'.$album_name, 0744);
    mkdir('uploads/thumbs/'.$album_name, 0744);
}
```

Why is there a fatal error, do I use `unix_timestamp` wrong here? And how can I solve this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: `UNIX_TIMESTAMP` is a MySQL function, not a PHP one.

Comment: You probably want time();

Answer (score 2):

`UNIX_TIMESTAMP()` isn't a PHP function.  Furthermore, you've already got it in your SQL and there's no `:timestamp` parameter in the SQL string.  So just lose the `':timestamp' => UNIX_TIMESTAMP()` and you should be good.

Also, your session_id part is messed up.  First you're dumping the session id directly into the SQL string, and then you're adding it to the parameter array, but with the value and key reversed.

Answer (score 1):

`UNIX_TIMESTAMP` is a MySQL function, not a PHP one.  You don't need to bind a param to `UNIX_TIMESTAMP`, you can just use it in your query.

Get rid of the `':timestamp' => UNIX_TIMESTAMP()`, this is your issue.  First `UNIX_TIMESTAMP` is not a PHP function, and `:timestamp` is nowhere in your query.

Also, `':session_id'` should be the key.

UPDATE: You need to use `prepare`/`execute` instead of `query` to run prepared statements.

```
$stmt = $database->prepare("INSERT INTO albums(id, timestamp, name, description) VALUES (':session_id', UNIX_TIMESTAMP(), ':album_name', ':album_description')");
$stmt->execute(array(
    ':session_id' => $_SESSION[id],
    ':album_name' => $album_name,
    ':album_description' => $album_description
));
```

I'm assuming `album_id` is AUTO_INCREMENT.  If not, you should add it to the query.

Comment: Ah okay, that makes sense to me, thanks a lot. There is now data in the database but the id = 0 and the album_name is :album_name and album_description is :album_description. Is then the array not reaching the databse or can it be that the filled in data is not reaching the array?

Comment: @Robske: I didn't notice this when I made this answer, you are making a prepared statement, so you can't use `query`, you need `execute`.  Check the updated answer.

Comment: I think both of your answers are good but now I get an error Fatal error: Call to undefined method database::prepare() in/...  I didn't know I had to define a method or isn't it that, are there other causes?

Comment: @Robske: What is `$database`?  You are using PDO, right?  Because you should have [`prepare`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php).

Answer (score 0):

UNIX_TIMESTAMP() is not a PHP function, is from MYSQL. Instead use time()

Answer (score 0):

Rocket Hazmat,
the database comes from member.php;

```
require_once('config.inc.php');
require_once("database.class.php");
require_once("member.class.php");
require("album.func.php");
require("image.func.php");
require("thumb.func.php");
/* Start an instance of the Database Class */
$database = new database("xxx", "xxx", "xxx", "xxx");
/* Create an instance of the Member Class */
$member = new member();
```

the database.class.php is;

class database {

```
public $pdo = null;


public $statement = null;


 * Database Constructor
 * 
 * This method is used to create a new database object with a connection to a datbase
 */
public function __construct() {
    /* Try the connections */
    try {
        /* Create a connections with the supplied values */
        $this->pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=" . Config::read('hostname') . ";dbname=" . Config::read('database') . "", Config::read('username'), Config::read('password'), Config::read('drivers'));


/*
 * Database Query
 * 
 * This method is used to create a new database prepared query
 * 
 * @param string $query The prepared statement query to the database
 * @param array|string $bind All the variables to bind to the prepared statement
 * @return return the executed string
 */
public function query($query, $bind = null, $fetch = 'FETCH_ASSOC') {
    /* Prepare the query statement */
    $this->statement = $this->pdo->prepare($query);
    /* Bind each value supplied from $bind */
    if($bind != null) {
        foreach($bind as $select => $value) {
            /* For each type of value give the appropriate param */
            if(is_int($value)) {
                $param = PDO::PARAM_INT; 
            } elseif(is_bool($value)) {
                $param = PDO::PARAM_BOOL;
            } elseif(is_null($value)) {
                $param = PDO::PARAM_NULL;
            } elseif(is_string($value)) {
                $param = PDO::PARAM_STR;
            } else {
                $param = FALSE;
            }
            /* Bid value */
            if($param) {
                $this->statement->bindValue($select, $value, $param);
            }
        }
    }
    /* Execute Query & check for any errors */
    if(!$this->statement->execute()){
        $result = array(
            1 => 'false',
            2 => '<b>[DATABASE] Error - Query:</b> There was an error in sql syntax',
        );
        return $result;
    }
    /* Return all content */
    if($fetch == 'FETCH_ASSOC') {
        $result = $this->statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    } elseif($fetch == 'FETCH_BOTH') {
        $result = $this->statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOTH);
    } elseif($fetch == 'FETCH_LAZY') {
        $result = $this->statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_LAZY);
    } elseif($fetch == 'FETCH_OBJ') {
        $result = $this->statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    } elseif($fetch == 'fetchAll') {
        $result = $this->statement->fetchAll();
    }
    return $result;
}
```

}